# Path to Custom Resource Folder

Tags: dll, windows-10, uwp

I created a new Folder in my Class-Library Project, calles "Resources". There i added an icon with the name "icon.png". 
 
The properties of the icon are:
Build Action: Embedded Resource 
Copy to Outpur Directory: Copy always

Now i want to use the icon in my Library and in the project, which has a reference to the .dll of the Library.

I already tried to get it with the BaseUri + "Resource/icon.png", but the complete Resource-Folder isn´t copied, when I build the Class-Library.

So how can I setup my Class-Library, that I can get the Icon/Resource-Folder in my Library and in projects, that reference to the .dll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the image as Content and Do not copy or Embedded Resource and Copy always and read it in XAML:

```
  <Image Source="ms-appx:///ClassLibraryNamespace/Resources/icon.jpg"/>
```

where ClassLibraryNamespace is your library name.

In code behind is the same with a

```
Source = new Uri("ms-appx:///ClassLibraryNamespace/Resources/icon.jpg");
```

Remember that are 3 slashes in the application path.

Comment: Works great. I didn´t know that i have to mention the ClassLibraryNamespace. Thank you